# Ios Swift Date Convert from TimeZone

Tags: ios, swift, date

```
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "KST")
    let nowstring = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    let nowdate = dateFormatter.date(from: nowstring)
    print(nowstring)
    print(nowdate)
```

print this `2018-07-24T15:06:26
Optional(2018-07-24 06:06:26 +0000)`

i want nowdate value `2018-07-24T15:06:26`

but String to Date without timezone

I have to use to `timeIntervalSince` so nowdate is must have timezone

Answer (score 0):

```
let today = NSDate()
print("\(today)")


let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let nowDatestring = formatter.string(from: today)

formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "KST")
let kstDate = formatter.date(from: nowDatestring)
print("\(kstDate!)")


formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "PST")
let pstDate = formatter.date(from: nowDatestring)
print("\(pstDate!)")


formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "IST")
let istDate = formatter.date(from: nowDatestring)
print("\(istDate!)")
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date` is a specific point in time, which is independent of time zone.  If you print a date value it will be always independent of any calendar or time zone. It will give same value for you(KST) and me(IST). You can specify your time zone when you format it using `DateFormatter`.